# MSMQ in cluster

Tags: msmq, windows-clustering

I configured MSMQ to run in cluster. Cluster consists of two Hyper-V virtual machines and uses common storage on third virtual machine (all virtual machines share windows domain and they see each other through the network). The fail-over cluster manager snap-in shows that MSMQ service is running. The non-clustered MSMQ services on machines, which are members of cluster, are shown to be runnung in services snap-in. Now I try to send message from remote computer (from third virtual machine) to clustered MSMQ service and to non-clustered MSMQ services. I use the following queue names:

- FormatName:Direct=OS:{clustered-msmq-netbios-name}\private$\{queueName}
- FormatName:Direct=TCP:{clustered-msmq-ip-address}\private$\{queueName}
- FormatName:Direct=TCP:{non-clustered-msmq-ip-address}\private$\{queueName}

When non-clustered msmq ip address is specified the message is delivered to non-clustered msmq instance. But when I try to access clustered msmq instance the sent message stays in outgoing message queue and it says "Waiting to connect" (Failed to connect Winsock socket). And queue on clustered msmq instance is empty.

I tried to connect to clustered msmq service with telnet. For connection I specified clustered msmq ip-address and port 1801. It says "Could not open connection to the host, on port 1801: Connect failed".

Any idea?

Additional information. When I click on "Manage Message Queueing" menu item when both cluster servers are online then in the snap-in there is no Message Queue item in the tree. When I pause one server (the second) there appears Message Queueing item in the tree. And when there is a Message Queueing item in the tree the messages start to be processed (I see them disappear from outgoing message queue on sending server, but I don't see them appear on receiving server).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can manage clustered message queueing only from that cluster node, which is now owner of role. On cluster node, which now is not active, there is no "Manage Message Queueing" menu item.

And considering the issue that messages were not delivered to clustered msmq instance I just reinstalled msmq windows feature on one of cluster nodes and recreated msmq cluster role. After these manipulations delivering messages just started working.

Comment: On disappearing messages, you need to enable negative journaling. Then you will see them appear in the dead letter queue with information as to why they were rejected. For example, if the delivery address of the message doesn't match the name of the destination queue manager then the message is discarded.